# The percentage of scores above the average . This function should accept two parameters: the list of scores and the average

Tags: python, function

Whenever I run the function to calculate the percentage of scores above the average I get the output 56.301. The correct answer should be 34. The average is 54.8415588235294.

```
#This function calls on the data file
def get_meet_scores_from_file():
        input_file = open('state_meet.txt','r')
        all_around_points = []
        aline = input_file.readline()

        while aline:
            values = aline.split(',')
            all_around_points.append(float(values[2]))
            aline = input_file.readline()
        input_file.close()
        return all_around_points

    #This function calculates the average.   
    def average_scores(score_list):
        average_of_scores = 0
        list_length = len(score_list)
        for index in range (list_length):
            list_item = score_list[index]
            average_of_scores = average_of_scores + (list_item / list_length)
        return average_of_scores

    # This is the function that is causing the problem.
    #I am trying to get the code to count the number of scores above the average [enter link description here][1]so I can continue and with the code to determine the percentage.
    def percentage_above_average(score_list,average):
        above_average = score_list[0]
        for i in range(int(above_average)):
            if above_average > average:
                above_average = above_average + 1
            return above_average
```

Comment: so far the only thing I am trying to accomplish in the function percentage_above_average is counting the number of scores above the average. I know it is not going to calculate the percentage yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic in `percentage_above_average` makes no sense. All you're doing is taking the first score in `score_list`, adding `1` if it's above the average score, and returning that number. That just gives you a particular score, incremented by `1` in this instance; it's not a percentage or count of anything.

What you need to do is loop through `score_list`, count scores higher than the average, and divide that count by `len(score_list)`. The code would look something like this:

```
def percentage_above_average(score_list,average):
    above_average = 0
    list_length = len(score_list)
    for index in range (list_length):
        if score_list[index] > average:
            above_average = above_average + 1
    return above_average / list_length
```

Answer (score 0):

The percentage of scores above the average will be the number of scores above the average divided by the total number of scores.

Here's a nice little way to count the number of something in an iterable that meets some condition

```
sum(1 for i in iterable if some_condition(i))
```

And of course we can get the total number of scores by getting the length of the list containing them

```
len(score_list)
```

So we can put those together to make our function

```
def percentage_above_average(score_list,average):
    above_count = sum(1 for score in score_list if score > average)
    return above_count/len(score_list)
```